# How to extend the Windows Explorer Context Menu with .NET6?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-6.0, windows-explorer

There is a good way to interact with the Windows Explorer shell for .NET Framework (see https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell#shell-context-menus).

Is that approach from ShareShell (interacting through COM servers) still the correct way for a new .NET6 or .NET7 application targeting Windows 10 and Windows 11 only?

Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu, is it the right entry point to implement?

I didn't found any nuget package or other site describing a good solution for the current .NET and Windows platforms.

I would prefer a solution without COM if there is one because my knowledge related to COM is limited.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Shell extensions *are* COM extensions. Except for the mobile-style gestures etc which were introduced with Windows 8 and later, and are available through UWP, WinRT, WinUI. Some basic functionality can be configured through the registry too, eg verbs and commands

Comment: I want to integrate some static as well as dynamic items in the context menu when for example the context menu of any folder is selected. I agree that the simplest way is to add registry keys, but then its limited to static entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classic [static verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers#customizing-a-shortcut-menu-using-static-verbs) can be added without writing code, just add it to the registry:

```
HKCR\.myext\=myextfile
HKCR\myextfile\shell\open\command\="c:\apps\myapp.exe" "%1"
```

To appear in the new menu in Windows 11 you have to implement the `IExplorerCommand` COM object and you have to be a packaged app with identity.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see this note about Windows 11. At the moment I do not have a development client with Win11, but this seems to be mandatory when I want to create a  compatible solution for Win10 and Win11.

Comment: The simple static method will work on 11 of course but it will be one extra click away to get to the old menu.